# PHP - Undefined index error

Tags: php, forms

This is my form with a file input field named `photo`:

```
<form action = "spremi-film.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <div class="grid_2">Naslov:</div>
    <div class="grid_10"><input type="text" name="naslov" value="" /></div>

    <div class="grid_2">Žanr: </div>
    <div class="grid_10"><?php izborZanra();   ?></div>

    <div class="grid_2">Godina: </div>
    <div class="grid_10"><?php izborGodine();   ?></div>

    <div class="grid_2">Trajanje:</div>
    <div class="grid_10"><input type="text" name="trajanje" value="" /></div>

    <div class="grid_2">Izbor slike:</div>
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />-->
    <div class="grid_10"><input type="file" name="photo"  /></div>


    <div class="grid_12"><input type="submit" value="SPREMI" /></div>
</form>
```

After that i put this code:

```php
$uploaddir = '/slike';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

//echo '<pre>';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    echo 'Slika je uspješno spremljena!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Slika nije spremljena!';
}

//print_r($_FILES);

//echo '</pre>';
```

When I run this I get an `undefined index: photo` notice in my browser.

Comment: Not enough information. What does the (presumably) HTML page that generates the request look like?

Comment: Just wrap this code inside `if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) { }`

Comment: Be careful of users uploading php files. You should check there image files...

Comment: you lack any error handling/checking in your upload code and simply assume the upload succeded. I also hope that `/slike` dir is NOT within your document root, because if it is, you're wide open to having your server totally destroyed by the first malicious user to come along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `$_FILES['photo']` is only defined when the user uploads a file, not during the first execution of the script while displaying the form.

Check with `isset($_FILES['photo'])` before accessing the variable in the `$uploadfile = ...` and `if (move_uploaded_file(...` lines.

Comment: somewhat wrong. first check if a post has actually occurred, e.g. `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`, THEN check for the upload stuff.

Comment: Why? You can't really set $_FILES without a post, so the additional test would be redundant.

Comment: safer to check a known fixed invariant value first. consider the OP changing the name of the field in the form, but forgetting to change the if(isset()) stuff.  silly, yes, but does add a little more butt-covering

Comment: I don't understand. If the field name changes in the form only, the result would be exactly the same in both scenarios (with or without the post check).

Comment: I've seen far too many people here doing `if (isset($_POST['somefield']))` to block off the post handler code.